# unable to find gps lock

Tags: android, gps

I have an app which sends GPS coordinates after a fixed time via SMS. It was working fine but now when I run it crashes on launch and GPS icon on my device blinks and never gets stable. I don't know whether the problem is in GPS system or there is something went wrong in my app or device. I have added all the permissions in manifest file.

code of main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startLocationTracking();

}

private void startLocationTracking()
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmintent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent sender1=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 100, alarmintent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

    try {
        am.cancel(sender1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("exjfkd"+e);
    }

    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND,5);


    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*10, sender1);
    System.out.println("start timer");
}
}
```

code of receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

long time = 10 * 1000; 
long distance = 10; 

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("alarm receiver....");

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, time,
            distance, locationListener);
  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

  String phoneNo = "+994580556";

  String Text = "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +" Longitude = " + location.getLongitude();
   try {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Text, null, null);
    Log.i("Send SMS", "");

   Toast.makeText(context, "message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS faild, please try again.",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
 } 

}

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
};

}
```

and my second question is how can I prevent it from being crashing if it is not find the GPS.

logcat

```
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.locationupdates.AlarmReceiver:       java.lang.NullPointerException
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2565)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:165)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at com.example.locationupdates.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:55)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2558)
 10-15 17:26:27.745: E/AndroidRuntime(5018):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you post errors that you have in LogCat?

Comment: I have added the logCat.

Comment: The source of the error is in the stack trace. Look for the first line that mentions your own class. In this example it is "com.example.locationupdates.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:55)". Go to AlarmReceiver.java line 55 and look for object references. One of those causes the NPE. When you know the reference that causes the error, you can look for where it came from and try to fix the actual error. This advice does not apply just to this case but pretty much all NullPointerExeptions you encounter from now on.

Comment: I have just found that my app is working with disabled gps and when i turn on gps then it gives me this crash.

Answer (score 1):

From the [LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)):

Returns the last known location for the provider, or null.

So you should check if null was returned. Obviously null is returned if there is no last known location.

Comment: please tell me what other method should i use to get the location.

Comment: Google: "android location api"